# Can CiviEvent widget show thumbnails?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, widget

I'm in the process of switching from Events Manager to CiviEvents so my client can integrate event registrations and payments into Civi. 
[image: screenshot]
However, as far as I can see there's no facility for the CiviEvents widget to show event thumbnails, which is a shame. Attached is a screenshot of the current set-up, where the Events Manager widget formatting matches the recent posts widget.

I can show an image by including it in the CiviEvent widget description field, but that's far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

For those using Drupal -> you can use Drupal Views to create such displays - here's an example of a CiviCRM Event Display - using a Bootstrap Grid (responsive display):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[CiviCRM Event Organiser](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser) can do this, but requires the [Event Organiser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/) plugin for display of events via the usual templating methods in WordPress. I don't know if there's a way to migrate your existing events from Events Manager to Event Organiser, but if your events are held in CiviCRM, then that won't matter.

Here's [an example of upcoming events](https://spirit-of-football.de/events/event/upcoming-events/), a [tag archive](https://spirit-of-football.de/events/schlagworte/erfurt/) and [the out-of-the-box calendar](https://spirit-of-football.de/kalender/). Event Organiser also provides a couple of configurable widgets, IIRC.